# How to check if a string contains only #

Tags: c#

I have a string  like "# # # # #" 
another string like "123 # abc # xyz"

I need to check if the string contains only # .How to achieve this.

I tried using  contains ,but this does not work .

Comment: not a duplicate, since OP wants to ignore whitespace

Comment: @André the exact problem statement or title of a possible duplicate doesn't have to match; it's the greater idea that is exactly the same. That question shows how to compare each character in a string; changing that comparison to ignore whitespace is trivial.

Answer (score 11):

Providing that the String is *not null*, the possible solution can be:

```
String text = "123#abc#xyz";
Boolean result = text.All((x) => x == '#');
```

In case the *white spaces* should be *ignored* (e.g. *"# # # # #"* considered being the right string)

```
String text = "123#abc#xyz";
Boolean result = text.All((x) => x == '#' || Char.IsWhiteSpace(x));
```

Comment: From OP's example of '# # # ...' looks like whitespaces needed to be ignored in the check.

Comment: @mockinterface: The question put it: "I need to check if the string contains only #". If, however, whitespaces should
be ignored just modify the All: "Boolean result =  text.All(x => x == '#' || Char.IsWhiteSpace(x))";

Comment: The bicycle isn't mine :) nevertheless, it'd be probably better to add this as an alternative snippet to the answer itself, in case the OP indeed means "# #" as a string which matches the requirements.

Comment: @kain64b: What are these two nots (!text ... !=) for? The original code is easier to read

Comment: @Dmitry I think its better to find any character exists other than "#" using Any. It will give result quickly. Check my answer below. Just a thought :)

Comment: @Naveen: Linq is smart enough to return "false" while executing "All" whenever condition doesn't meet. Both All and Any in this case have the same performance

Answer (score 4):

```
bool IsSharpOnly(string str)
{ 
   for(int i = 0; i < str.Length ; i++)
   {
       if (str[i] != '#')
           return false;
   }

   return true;
```

}

Comment: "foreach" loop instead of "for" one will make your solution more elegant, IMHO

Comment: +1 because i'm fan of old school for's over linq for simple objects/expresions :)

Comment: but does not recognize whitespaces

Answer (score 3):

Another solution with a Regex:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^#+$");
bool b1 = r.IsMatch("asdas#asdas");
bool b2 = r.IsMatch("#####");
```

**Edit**
Was not sure if white space should be ignored or not, if so:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[\\s*#+]+$");
```

Comment: liked this, but need also check for whitespaces..

Comment: I was wondering about that from the example but it wasn't mentioned in the question so I assumed it was just the OP's formatting. Will edit.

Answer (score 2):

With a regular expression?

Like this: "([0-9]+)|([a-z]+)"

you can check if the input string does not match.

For instance for the string contains `'#'` only:

```
  String text = "123#abc#xyz";
  Boolean result = Regex.Match(text, "^#*$").Success;
```

Comment: When having idea, please provide a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
string ss = "##g#";

if ((ss.Split('#').Length - 1).Equals(ss.Length))
{
  //Contains only #
}
```

Comment: There's a serious drawback in your solution: it creates an array which is not wanted

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
private bool CheckIfStringContainsOnlyHash(string value)
{
    return !value.Where(a => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a.ToString()) && a != '#').Select(a => true).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dmitry's example is probably the most elegant, but something like this could work too (again assuming the input has been null checked):

```
string test = "#####";
return test.Replace("#", "").Length == 0;
```

EDIT: picking up on the discussion about ignoring whitespace too, we could use:

```
string test = "#####";
return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(test.Replace("#", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
  string txt = "123#abc#xyz";
        if (!txt.Any((X) => X != '#'))
        { 
           //Contains only '#'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is also a solution

```
String data= "###########";
bool isAllSame = data.All(d => d == '#');
if(isAllSame)
{
// code when string contain only #
}
```